# How read excel file in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, xls, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have data in excel file. How read that file line by line and data insert in database? Maybe add upload control and after click on button in .py file read line by line.

For example:

1    John   Stern

2    Mike   Hox

3    Julia  Max

Any example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first time, you need determinating, what package would you like used to read your excel file.

I found this website (http://www.python-excel.org/), you can found the little list of python package.

In my case I used openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
from openerp import models, fields, api, _
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

class ExcelReader(models.TransientModel):
    _name="reader_excel"

    excel_file = fields.Binary(string='Excel File')

    def import_excel(self):
        # Generating of the excel file to be read by openpyxl
        file = self.excel_file.decode('base64')
        excel_fileobj = TemporaryFile('wb+')
        excel_fileobj.write(file)
        excel_fileobj.seek(0)

        # Create workbook
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_fileobj, data_only=True)
        # Get the first sheet of excel file
        sheet = workbook[workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]]

        # Iteration on each rows in excel
        for row in sheet.rows:
            # Get value
            v1 = row[0].value 
            v2 = row[1].value 
            v3 = row[2].value 
            # Create your record 
            self.env['your_model'].creaate({'val1':v1,'val2':v2, 'val3':v3'})
```

It's a little example. You need adapting for your situation.

Comment: Tnx for help, One question what is easiest way to install openpyxl, I use Ubuntu and eclipse.

Comment: It's a pip package, You can used sudo pip install openpyxl

Comment: Tnx for last comment,  Now after call function get NameError: global name 'TemporaryFile' is not defined.

Comment: Sorry my bad I've missing one import from tempfile import TemporaryFile